# Jekyll: How to template to get <header> tags in markdown

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

Currently I have a page which I've templated such that the header and footer are all sorted and I just need to do my actual content. In my content section I have:

```
<header> **subsection title** </header>
<section **content ** <section>
<header> **subsection 2 title** </header>
<section **content 2 ** <section>
```

I ideally want my pages to be written in markdown but I make the page

```
<header> **subsection title** </header>
<section **content markdown ** <section>
```

Jekyll then fails to process this correctly.

What is the correct way of constructing a page with multiple tags which each require variables in Jekyll?

My assumption would be I could redefine `<h2>` tags somehow so that they produce a `<header>` tag instead but that seems like overkill.
My other assumption would be to wrap the `<section>` content in a special tag to force it to be read as markdown? Again that seems a bit of an odd way to do it.

Any advice welcome!

Comment: "Jekyll then fails to process this correctly": what do you mean? Do you have errors during page generation?

Comment: I don't know if it a reason, but on both your examples you are missing the closing `>` on the opening `section` tag.

Comment: ... and missing slashes on the end tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be that you are using two header tags. Try using a different tag for the second header.